# Using Wix - how do display warning according to return state - using Check=ifnore

Tags: wix, installation

I'm new to wix and have a very important question
My installer should ignore the return status- meaning it should complete successfully but I do need to display to the user a warning with the return status in case it did not succeed.
or even better check the code and analyze accordingly
how do I do it with wix installer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WiX generates MSI files, and when they run you don't have any control over what the return value will be. You also may be unaware that it's a transactional install. If it works it works and everything is fine, if it fails then it will rollback and restore the system to its starting point. This behavior can be screwed up to a certain extent if you add your own code (in a custom action) to change the system and then don't write rollback code to undo what you did, but there is no partial install that you need to warn anyone about.

Answer (score 0):

In your Wix project file, you could insert the Warning task

at the appropriate place.